# Razor escape quotes in HTML

Tags: html, razor

I'd like to use `@row.TempOrderID` as the query string variable in my `onclick` event but it's not passing correctly in my code. Probably a syntax issue.

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<div class="dg-scroll-horizontal">
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered" style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Company</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Person</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr>
     @foreach (var row in BSDB.TempOrderA("TempOrderID='" + TknParams.TempOrderID + "'")) {
    <tr>
      <td>@row.OrganizationType</td>
      <td>@row.CC_Company</td>
      <td>@row.CC_Contact</td>
      <td>@row.CC_Phone</td>
      <td>@row.CC_Email</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn btn-info" href="/dev/Client-Info" onclick="return dnnModal.show('/dev/Client-Info?popUp=true&TempOrderID=@row.TempOrderID',true,550,550,false)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Adding two sets of double quotes `""` does escape correctly but then my URL is not properly formatted IE:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="/dev/Client-Info" onclick="return dnnModal.show('/dev/Client-Info?popUp=true&amp;TempOrderID=" "2""',true,550,550,false)"=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

Comment: What's the generated HTML?

Comment: It's a table with a button that opens a pop-up and I need the querystring value for TempOrderID to read the proper number. This is why i've used @row.TempOrderID after the `=` sign but seems that the single quotes`'` of the `onclick` HTML is not rendering my C#

Comment: If i use double quotes it does pull  in my ID number but then renders like this: `<a class="btn btn-info" href="/dev/Client-Info" onclick="return dnnModal.show('/dev/Client-Info?popUp=true&amp;TempOrderID=" "2""',true,550,550,false)"=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>` which dosent read correctly in the browser